# How to keep go memory usage down?

Tags: memory, go, garbage-collection

I have a go program that is using too much memory and therefore getting killed, so I want to try and keep memory usage down. Here's a simplified silly version of what I'm doing, revealing the problem:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "runtime"
    "runtime/debug"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    source := "/tmp/1G.source"
    repeats, _ := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[1])
    m := &runtime.MemStats{}

    err := exec.Command("dd", "if=/dev/zero", "of="+source, "bs=1073741824", "count=1").Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to create 1GB file: %s\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("created 1GB source file, %s\n", memory_usage(m))

    // read it multiple times
    switch os.Args[2] {
    case "1":
        fmt.Println("re-using a byte slice and emptying it each time")
        // var data []byte
        for i := 1; i <= repeats; i++ {
            data, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(source)
            if len(data) > 0 { // just so we use data
                data = nil
            }
            fmt.Printf("did read %d, %s\n", i, memory_usage(m))
        }
    case "2":
        fmt.Println("ignoring the return value entirely")
        for i := 1; i <= repeats; i++ {
            ioutil.ReadFile(source)
            fmt.Printf("did read %d, %s\n", i, memory_usage(m))
        }
    case "3":
        fmt.Println("ignoring the return value entirely, forcing memory freeing")
        for i := 1; i <= repeats; i++ {
            ioutil.ReadFile(source)
            debug.FreeOSMemory()
            fmt.Printf("did read %d, %s\n", i, memory_usage(m))
        }
    }

    // wait incase garbage collection needs time to do something
    <-time.After(5 * time.Second)

    fmt.Printf("all done, %s\n", memory_usage(m))

    os.Exit(0)
}

func memory_usage(m *runtime.MemStats) string {
    runtime.ReadMemStats(m)
    return fmt.Sprintf("system memory: %dMB; heap alloc: %dMB; heap idle-released: %dMB", int((m.Sys/1024)/1024), int((m.HeapAlloc/1024)/1024), int(((m.HeapIdle-m.HeapReleased)/1024)/1024))
}
```

If I call this with `main 7 2` I get:

```
created 1GB source file, system memory: 2MB; heap alloc: 0MB; heap idle-released: 1MB
ignoring the return value entirely
did read 1, system memory: 4233MB; heap alloc: 3072MB; heap idle-released: 1024MB
did read 2, system memory: 4233MB; heap alloc: 3072MB; heap idle-released: 1024MB
did read 3, system memory: 4233MB; heap alloc: 3072MB; heap idle-released: 1024MB
did read 4, system memory: 4233MB; heap alloc: 3072MB; heap idle-released: 1023MB
did read 5, system memory: 6347MB; heap alloc: 3584MB; heap idle-released: 2559MB
did read 6, system memory: 6347MB; heap alloc: 3072MB; heap idle-released: 3071MB
did read 7, system memory: 6347MB; heap alloc: 3072MB; heap idle-released: 3071MB
all done, system memory: 6347MB; heap alloc: 3072MB; heap idle-released: 3071MB
```

Perhaps off-topic, but is it expected that reading in a 1GB file results in 4GB of system memory usage?

Anyway, Ideally I want an unlimited number of identical loops to use a ~constant amount of memory, instead of increasing from 4GB to 6GB.

So I thought forcing freeing of memory would help, but `main 7 3` gives:

```
created 1GB source file, system memory: 1MB; heap alloc: 0MB; heap idle-released: 0MB
ignoring the return value entirely, forcing memory freeing
did read 1, system memory: 4237MB; heap alloc: 0MB; heap idle-released: 0MB
did read 2, system memory: 4237MB; heap alloc: 0MB; heap idle-released: 0MB
did read 3, system memory: 6351MB; heap alloc: 0MB; heap idle-released: 0MB
did read 4, system memory: 6351MB; heap alloc: 0MB; heap idle-released: 0MB
did read 5, system memory: 6351MB; heap alloc: 0MB; heap idle-released: 0MB
did read 6, system memory: 6351MB; heap alloc: 0MB; heap idle-released: 0MB
did read 7, system memory: 6351MB; heap alloc: 0MB; heap idle-released: 0MB
all done, system memory: 6351MB; heap alloc: 0MB; heap idle-released: 0MB
```

How can I keep the memory usage down for all loops?

Following suggestions in the comments, I tried a new case:

```
case "4":
    fmt.Println("doing a streaming read")
    b := make([]byte, 10000, 10000)
    for i := 1; i <= repeats; i++ {
        f, _ := os.Open(source)
        r := bufio.NewReader(f)
        for {
            _, err := r.Read(b)
            if err != nil {
                break
            }
        }
        fmt.Printf("did read %d, %s\n", i, memory_usage(m))
    }
}
```

But I still get memory usage increase with number of loops:

```
created 1GB source file, system memory: 1MB; heap alloc: 0MB; heap idle-released: 0MB
doing a streaming read
did read 1, system memory: 1MB; heap alloc: 0MB; heap idle-released: 0MB
did read 2, system memory: 1MB; heap alloc: 0MB; heap idle-released: 0MB
did read 3, system memory: 1MB; heap alloc: 0MB; heap idle-released: 0MB
did read 4, system memory: 1MB; heap alloc: 0MB; heap idle-released: 0MB
did read 5, system memory: 2MB; heap alloc: 0MB; heap idle-released: 0MB
did read 6, system memory: 2MB; heap alloc: 0MB; heap idle-released: 0MB
did read 7, system memory: 2MB; heap alloc: 0MB; heap idle-released: 0MB
all done, system memory: 2MB; heap alloc: 0MB; heap idle-released: 0MB
```

To generalise the question, when you're using 3rd party functions (ie. where you have no control over how they're using memory within themselves) in a loop, and are doing the exact same thing every time in the loop, is there any way to force Go to re-use the memory it has already allocated instead of requesting more from the OS?

Comment: You reduce memory by not creating garbage, and reusing memory when possible. Watching the gctrace output is usually much more useful for determining what the garbage collector is doing.

Comment: Yes, but in this example with the very simple loop, how can I force go to reuse the memory?

Comment: You're reading huge files into memory, and wondering why it's using memory? I don't really understand the question. What behavior do you expect, or hope to achieve?

Comment: @sbs: you force it to reuse memory by reusing the memory, i.e. read the file into the same buffer each time.

Comment: ... which is outside of my control for ioutil.ReadFile()? So I should just use something where I have the necessary control?

Comment: Do you need to read the full file with ioutil? For example read line by line with the bufio package?

Comment: @Steve101 no, I don't have to use ioutil. I'm seeing now that my test was too silly and something more realistic wouldn't have caused me problems.

Comment: @Steve101, I can't figure out how to actually re-use the same buffer using something like bufio. I have: `b := make([]byte, 10000, 10000)
  for i := 1; i <= repeats; i++ {
   f, _ := os.Open(source)
   r := bufio.NewReader(f)
   l := 0
   for {
    _, err := r.Read(b)
    if err != nil {
     break
    }
    l++
   }
   fmt.Printf("did read %d (%d loops), %s\n", i, l, memory_usage(m))
  }` but system memory still increases with loops (though the scale is smaller: 1MB to 2MB).

Comment: @sbs I would work through this blog - https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs. You could force `runtime.GC()` which may reduce the increase.